# Can we shutdown shared EC2 image after transfer to another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am new to the AWS and learning lot through the support docs. Though I have created an AMI for EC2 instance of one account to transfer it to the another account successfully by reading docs/procedures. I have launched that image after creating a snapshot and it's there in second account.

Now my question is, is it safe or may have any problem if I delete/stop/shutdown instance from first account? Does the instance of second account will run smoothly or not?

**EDITED:**

Below accepted answer resolve my issue and i get more information about this from here. May it'll also help you out. Check here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah/awsgsg-wah.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, terminating the instance from the first account is fine

If the AMI is "shared" to the other account and hasn't been duplicated within it then keeping the AMI is probably a good idea, in case you wish to re-launch it

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer. It has running server and web services also. To make it looks like first one what changes require in the destination? Do you know that?